# Give an example of $f$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$ but $\lim_{x \to 0} (f \circ f)(x) \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Unfortunately I don't have much to offer with regards to 'work in progress'. I've tried a dozen drawings and know I have find $f$ which satisfies:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0 \ \forall x: 0 < |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon \ \ \text{and} \\
&\exists \epsilon' > 0 \ \forall \delta>0 \ \exists x: (0 < |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon) \ \ \text{but} |f(f(x)| \geq \epsilon' 
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Comment: Do you mean $x\to 0$ in the second part of the title too?

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried $f(x) = x$ and $a=1$?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Edited. Thanks.

Comment: If $f(x) \to 0$ what would you expect $f(f(x)) \to ?$

Comment: @copper.hat I would expect it to $f(f(x)) \to 0$.

Comment: You need to find a $\delta'$ such that if $|x| < \delta'$ then $|f(x)| <\delta$.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unintentionally misleading. I frequently forget the $0 < |x|$ part of the $\lim_{x \to 0}$.

Answer (score 2):

### Nevermind:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &x\neq 0\\
1 &x=0
\end{cases}$

The important bit is $0<|x|$ instead of $0\leq|x|$. The short notation $\lim_{x\to 0}$ is a bit misleading here. Look at the actual definition.
$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists\delta>0 \forall x:0<|x|<\delta⟹|f(x)|<\varepsilon$$

Now let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary, then for $\delta=1$, I can select any $0<|x|<\delta$ and have:
$$|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=0$$
Since we are explicitly not allowed to select $x=0$

---

The exercise is actually quite clever. It teaches you the difference between a removable discontinuity (cf. [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)) and a continuous function.

---

Original:

Such an f does not exist. Assume such an $f$ exists. Then for any sequence $x_n\to 0$, we know, that $f(x_n)\to0$. But if the second condition would hold, then for any $\delta>0$ I can find an $x$ with $|x|<\delta$ with $|f(f(x))|>\varepsilon'$. So I can find a sequence $x_n$ with

$$|x_n|<1/n \text{ and }|f(f(x_n))|>\varepsilon'.$$

Well now define $y_n=f(x_n)$. Then we know that $y_n\to 0$ due to condition one. But this implies (also due to condition one), that $f(y_n)\to 0$. Which is a contradiction.

Essentially the first condition says that $f$ is continuous in $0$. And thus $f\circ f$ is also continuous in $0$, since $f(0)=0$

Comment: The limit of your revised function at $0$ is equal to $1$?

Comment: No it is $0$, since you are not allowed to input $0$.

Comment: +1: I forget this $0<|x|$ part of limits all the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such $f$ with $f(x)\ne0$ for all $x$.

Assume $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$, and $f(x)\ne0$ for all $x$. Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$ implies $0<|f(x)|<\epsilon$. Furthermore there is a $\delta'$ such that $0<|x|<\delta'$ implies $0<|f(x)|<\delta$. This allows to conclude that
$$0<|x|<\delta'\quad\Rightarrow\quad 0<|f(x)|<\delta\quad\Rightarrow \quad0<\bigl|f(f(x))\bigr|<\epsilon\ .$$

When $f$ may take the value $0$ things are different. Consider
$$f(x):=x\sin{1\over x}\quad(x\ne0),\qquad f(0)=1\ .$$
Then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$, but there is a sequence $x_n:={1\over n\pi}\to0$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)=1$, and similarly a sequence $y_n\to0$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\bigl(f(y_n)\bigr)=0$. Therefore the $\lim_{x\to0}f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$ does not exist.

Comment: You are not allowed to pick $x=0$, when taking $x\to 0$ so it is actually possible to have a discontinuous function with removable discontinuity. See my answer.

Comment: @FelixB.: I don't take $x=0$ when studying $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ for the function $g:=f\circ f$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize you made the assertion that $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$